# Is it possible to start and stop Celery workers as a daemon only while a script is running?

Tags: python, celery

I'm experimenting using Celery for desktop application use instead of running it on a server. I would like to start the workers as daemon when the application starts and stop them when they are done.

I figured out how to stop them when I close out the application:

```
app.control.broadcast("shutdown")
```

But the only way I got it to run the app on it's own thread is this way:

```
argv = ['celeryTest', '--loglevel=info']
t = Thread(target=app.worker_main, args=(argv,))
t.start()
```

This seems like it works but I keep getting the following message.

> RuntimeWarning: Never call result.get() within a task! In Celery 3.2 this will result in an exception being
>   raised instead of just being a warning."

What am I doing wrong or what can I do more right?

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I got it working with result.result instead of result.get().